# @target pointcut throws IllegalStateException

Tags: aop, spring-aop, pointcut

In Spring boot AOP application I have a pointcut `@target(MyAnnotation) || @annotation(MyAnnotation)`. 
Advice should be executed if `MyAnnotation` is put either on executing object annotated with this annotation or on annotated method.

When I run application I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.log.Slf4jScopeDecorator
```

A similar problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775611/problems-with-aop-in-spring-boot) but there it seems that pointcut is too wide and mine is not as I have only few annotated classes with `MyAnnotation` in the project.

I put this annotation to feign client interface, like this.

```java
@MyAnnotation
@FeignClient(name="some-name", url="http://test.url")
public interface MyClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/endpoint")
    List<Store> getSomething();
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my pointcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after hours of investigation I replaced my pointcut with this one

```java
@Around("execution(* (@MyAnnotation *).*(..)) || execution(@MyAnnotation * *(..))")
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452483/3457177) I used only `execution` to avoid proxy creation. Hope this helps

Comment: Hey, some people actually use the search feature on SO, wow! I wish more people would do that. I am glad that my old answer helped you. ;-)